# Recovering an abelian category out of its derived category

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, abelian-categories, reference-request

I'm trying to learn more about derived category stuff and my curiosity has made me to ask these questions. Sorry if I'm being sloppy, I'm a new learner.

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_category#t-structures) it has been stated that since different abelian categories can give rise to equivalent derived categories, so it is *impossible* to reconstruct $\mathcal{A}$ (an abelian category) from its derived category $D(\mathcal{A}).$

1. To what extent it is *possible* to recover $\mathcal{A}?$ what would be the frame work for studying such questions?
2. Is there any notion of *moduli space of t-structures* on the derived category of a given abelian category?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The derived category of an abelian category has a t-structure, so obviously that's the first thing you want.
To a t-structure corresponds a heart, which is an abelian category, whose derived category might be different than the one you started with.
To further complicate matters, as you noted, you could have a heart whose derived category *is* actually equivalent to the one you started with, but the heart itself is not the original abelian category.

It's not clear what you can recover from a triangulated category alone, or even from a triangulated category + t-structure.
If you like algebraic geometry and are willing to consider additional structures then you can recover the abelian category. The derived category of a scheme, considered as a monoidal category (coming from tensor products) recovers the original scheme (and thus the abelian category).
The same is true if you start with a variety with an ample canonical bundle, then the category plus the bundle do recover the variety.

Somehow this flexibility of derived categories is a nice feature, as it gives rise to interesting (and hidden?) "symmetries" and "relationships" between spaces.

As per the second question I can only think of what Sasha said, that is stability conditions.
Given a stability condition one automatically gets a heart of a t-structure (which again may not have anything to do with the original abelian category) and the slices of the stability condition may be seen as a continuous family of t-structures. 
It would indeed be really nice to have such a thing as a moduli space of t-structures!

Comment: Dear Jacob, you can recover a variety with ample or anti-ample canonical bundle from its derived category alone, you don't need the canonical bundle.

Comment: dear Piotr, thanks for the correction, I always get the Bondal-Orlov stuff wrong!

Comment: Dear Jacob, thank you, those algebraic geometry examples are indeed very good motivations. 

Answer (score 8):

There is a notion of "Bridgeland stability condition" which includes a t-structure. Those have a reasonable moduli space. See papers of Bridgeland for details.